# How to constrain number of waves (as monotonic as possible) when smooth data in R?

Tags: r

`bfi` is big five personality sample data from `psych` package.  personality is stable then will not change fast when age grow.

```
bfi[bfi$gender=='2',] %>% mutate(.,q=(A1+A2+A3+A4+A5)/5) %>%
    ggplot(.,aes(x=age,y=q))+
    stat_summary_bin(fun.y="mean", geom="bar",breaks = seq(1,100,1))+
    geom_smooth(aes(x=age,y=q),colour="yellow")
```

The output of above codes as below:
[image]

The yellow line is smooth line,because personality is almost monotonic,smooth line only allowed to be pure monotonic(without peak,without valley) or has only one peak(or valley).

I tried `bfi %>% subset(.,gender=='2') %>% mutate(.,q = (A1+A2+A3+A4+A5)/5) %>% loess(q~age,data = .,) %>% predict(.,data.frame(age=seq(0,100,1)))` ,but result has 2 peaks.
[image]

How to constrain number of waves (as monotonic as possible) when smooth data in R?

Comment: could you provide sample data (`dput(<yourdata>)`) ?  Otherwise, its hard to reproduce this specific question.

Comment: @heck1,`library(psych)` will get `bfi`

Comment: My bad, will check it out tomorrow!