# How to remove rows and replace value by a complex condition?

Tags: r

The sample data as below:

```
> data.frame(age = c(13, 16, 13,18,16),math = c(4, 7, 8,6,6),total = c(5, 3, 6,5,7))
  age math total
1  13    4     5
2  16    7     3
3  13    8     6
4  18    6     5
5  16    6     7
```

The process is:for each `age`, keep only one row which `math`>5,replace `total` by sum `total`.

- For row 1,`math`=4,not >5,then keep this row.
- For row 2,
  `math`=6,>5,then looking for another row with the same `age` 16 and 
  `math`>5,which means row 5.Then (7+3)=10,replace `total` of row 2 by 
  `10`,and delete row 5.
- For row 3, the only match `age` is row 1,but
  `math` of row 1 <5,then keep row 3 as the same.
- For row 4, even 
  `math`>5,but no match `age` 18,then keep this row.

The expected result as below:

```
  age math total
1  13    4     5
2  16    7     10
3  13    8     6
4  18    6     5
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can divide the problem into two parts. For the first part we `filter` where `math > 5`, `group_by` `age` and take `first` value of `math` and `sum` of `total` and bind the rows where `math <= 5`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   filter(math > 5) %>%
   group_by(age) %>%
   summarise(math = first(math), 
            total = sum(total)) %>%
   bind_rows(df %>% filter(math <= 5))


#   age  math total
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    13     8     6
#2    16     7    10
#3    18     6     5
#4    13     4     5
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer!Could you pls have a look of another hard question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610324/how-to-constrain-number-of-waves-as-monotonic-as-possible-when-smooth-data-in